# How to pass parameter to 'A' restricted directive

Tags: angularjs

I want to pass parameter to 'A'(attribute) restricted directive's scope:

I have the following 'E' restricted directive

```
.directive("twValidation", function () {
return{
  restrict: "E",
  replace: true,
  scope: {
    field: '='
  },
  templateUrl: "partials/components/directives/common/tw-validation.tpl.html"
}
```

})

I use it like this:

```
<tw-validation field="myField"></tw-validation>
```

but eventually i want this:

```
<div tw-validation="myField">...</div>
```

How can I pass argument inside of attribute restricted directive?

Comment: I think setting scope: `{twValidation:'='}` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.directive("twValidation", function () {
return{
  restrict: "A",
  replace: true,
  scope: {
    twValidation: '='
  },
  templateUrl: "partials/components/directives/common/tw-validation.tpl.html"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try the following:

```
.directive("twValidation", function () {
return{
  restrict: "E",
  replace: true,
  scope: {
    field: '=field'
  },
  templateUrl: "partials/components/directives/common/tw-validation.tpl.html"
}



<tw-validation field="myField"></tw-validation>
```